# Matrices F and c for F test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, matrix, f-test

In $\mathcal{F}$ test, the hypotheses involve multiple regression coefficients with the $\mathcal{F}_{0}$ test statistic:
\begin{equation}
z_{j} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1} x_{1} + \beta_{2} x_{2} + ... + \beta_{n} x_{j} + \epsilon_{j} 
\end{equation} 
where Z is a dependent variable, $X$ the independent variable, and $\beta_{j} \in \mathbb{C}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ \cite{ahlfors, ftests}. 
The null hypothesis is $H_{0}: \mathbf{L} \beta = \mathbf{c}$ without joint hypothesis.

I think the general form of the matrix $L$ is difficult one for computation. 
Consider a joint hypothesis $H_{0}: \beta_{1} = \beta_{2} = 0$. 
This leads to a term $X'X$ that is a diagonal matrix, see [these](http://www.sts.uzh.ch/past/hs09/em/topic6_p.pdf) lecture notes. 
So the corresponding matrix of $\mathbf{L} := X'X$ is a diagonal matrix and $\mathbf{c} := [[0 0 ... 0]^{-1}$ is a null vector.

### Joint hypothesis

Here you can consider $\mathbf{L} \hat{\beta} - \mathbf{c} = 0$ for the regression of the observed value. 
For detailed steps, see the material of Zurich University, [here](http://www.sts.uzh.ch/past/hs09/em/topic6_p.pdf) and last part of it. 
The observed $\mathcal{F}$ test statistic is the following if the null hypothesis has a form $H_{0}: \beta_{1} = \beta_{2} = ... = \beta_{k} = 0$.

\begin{equation}
F_{0} = \frac{ \left( SSR_{r} - SSR_{ur} \right) / q }{ SSR_{ur} / \left(n - (k+1) \right)},
\end{equation}
where $SSR_{r}$ is the Sum of Squared Residuals of the restricted model, $SSR_{ur}$ is the same for the unrestricted model, and $n$ is the number of observations \cite{ftests} p. 4. 
This is similar to the one in Zurich University's materials.

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{X'X} =
\begin{bmatrix}
       \gamma_{1} & . & . & . & \gamma_{M+1} & 0 & . & . & . & 0 \\[0.3em]
       0 & . & \gamma_{1} & . & . & \gamma_{M+1} & 0 & . & . & 0 \\[0.3em]
       0 & 0 & 0 & . & . & 0 & \gamma_{1} & . & . & \gamma_{M+1}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

and the corresponding vector of $\mathbf{c} = [0 0 ... 0]^{-1}$ is a null vector here under $H_{0}$.

### Real values vs Complex values

For me both are ok, but complex values are for useful for future applications.
You can assume that the matrix $\mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ are real valued if it makes the analysis easier. 
[Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/66268/3017) however something about analysis with complex data.

### Matlab

In Matlab, you can do $\mathcal{F}$ test simply by

```
[h,p,ci,stats] = vartest2(J, model1)
[h2,p2,ci2,stats2] = vartest2(J, model2)
```

and compare the appropriate models. 
However, here, Matlab does not give you the values of the matrices. 
I would like to know in the context of Matlab, for instance, how it handles the matrices $\mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{c}$.

How can you present the matrices $\mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ for $\mathcal{F}$ test?

### My sources

- Complex analysis, Lars Ahlfors, 1979. (ahlfors)
- Statistical Concepts: A Second Course, Lomax R, 2007. (ftests)
- Some lecture materials from Zurich University Economic Department
- Some lecture materials from Stanford University Political Sciences

Comment: i am vevy curious to know how Ahlfor's stands as a reference for this question.

Comment: @aginensky He started to use Z for dependent variables and X for independent variables and I use his convention.

Comment: truly not important, but z in Ahlfor's book means a complex variable- z = x+iy typically with x,y real.

Comment: @aginensky See http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/66268/3017