# Find the rotation between set of points

Tags: r, data-transformation, geometry, rotation, procrustes-analysis

I have two sets (`sourc` and `target`) of points `(x,y)` that I would like to align. What I did so far is:

- find the centroid of each set of points
- use the difference between the centroids translations the point in `x` and `y`

What I would like is **to find the best rotation (in degrees) to align the points**.

Any idea?

M code is below (with plots to visualize the changes):

```
# Raw data
## Source data
sourc = matrix( 
     c(712,960,968,1200,360,644,84,360), # the data elements 
     nrow=2, byrow = TRUE)

## Target data
target = matrix( 
  c(744,996,980,1220,364,644,68,336), # the data elements 
  nrow=2, byrow = TRUE)

# Get the centroids
sCentroid <- c(mean(sourc[1,]), mean(sourc[2,])) # Source centroid
tCentroid <- c(mean(target[1,]), mean(target[2,])) # Target centroid

# Visualize the points
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(sourc[1,], sourc[2,], col="green", pch=20, main="Raw Data",
     lwd=5, xlim=range(sourceX, targetX),
     ylim=range(sourceY, targetY))
points(target[1,], target[2,], col="red", pch=20, lwd=5)
points(sCentroid[1], sCentroid[2], col="green", pch=4, lwd=2)
points(tCentroid[1], tCentroid[2], col="red", pch=4, lwd=2)

# Find the translation
translation <- tCentroid - sCentroid
target[1,] <- target[1,] - translation[1]
target[2,] <- target[2,] - translation[2]

# Get the translated centroids
tCentroid <- c(mean(target[1,]), mean(target[2,])) # Target centroid

# Visualize the translation
plot(sourc[1,], sourc[2,], col="green", pch=20, main="After Translation",
     lwd=5, xlim=range(sourceX, targetX),
     ylim=range(sourceY, targetY))
points(target[1,], target[2,], col="red", pch=20, lwd=5)
points(sCentroid[1], sCentroid[2], col="green", pch=4, lwd=2)
points(tCentroid[1], tCentroid[2], col="red", pch=4, lwd=2)
```

Comment: I cannot read your code, but the operation you need is called Procrustes rotation. Have you heard of it? It works when points are already paired ($x_i,y_i$). Pre-rotation optional operations include translation and scaling, and optional post-rotational isoscaling.

Comment: A [complex regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66088/) will do the job.

Comment: I've seen, that, rotating the system about 180 degrees, then the pairs $(a,C),(b,D),(c,A),(d,B)$ become neighbours - and this is even a better fit than the best fit of the original $(a,A),(b,B),(c,C),(d,D)$ *(where the small letters stand for vector `source` and capital letters for vector `target`)* I've not seen this possibility mentioned and explicitely allowed or disallowed. Are you sure that you don't want that better fit?

Answer (score 5):

This can be done using the [Kabsch Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm). The algorithm finds the best least-squares estimate for rotation of $RX-Y$ where $R$ is rotation matrix, $X$ and $Y$ are your target and source matrices with 2 rows and n columns.

In [[1](http://www.math.pku.edu.cn/teachers/yaoy/Fall2011/arun.pdf)] it is shown that this problem can be solved using singular value decomposition. The algorithm is as follows:

1. Center the datasets so their centroids are on origin.
2. Compute the "covariance" matrix $C$=$XY^T$.
3. Obtain the Singular Value Decomposition of $C=UDV^T$.
4. Direction adjustment $d=sign(det(C))$.
5. Then the optimal rotation $R=V\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & d \\ \end{array} \right)U^T$

I don't know of any implementation in R so wrote a small function
    below.

Your initial points:

```
src <- matrix(c(712,960,968,1200,360,644,84,360), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)
trg <- matrix(c(744,996,980,1220,364,644,68,336), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)
```

Kabsch algorithm in an R funtion:

```
kabsch2d <- function(Y, X) {
  X   <- X-rowMeans(X)
  Y   <- Y-rowMeans(Y)
  C   <- X %*% t(Y)
  SVD <- svd(C)
  D   <- diag(c(1, sign(det(C))))
  t(SVD$v) %*% D %*% t(SVD$u)
}
```

Center the points:

```
src <- src-rowMeans(src)
trg <- trg-rowMeans(trg)
```

Obtain rotation:

```
rot <- kabsch2d(src, trg)
```

Result (black - original source, red - original target, green - rotated target)

```
plot(t(src), col="black", pch=19)
points(t(trg), col="red", pch=19)
points(t(rot %*% trg), col="green", pch=19)
```

[image]

[1] http://www.math.pku.edu.cn/teachers/yaoy/Fall2011/arun.pdf

Comment: +1. However, the answer could be further much better if you included discourse about how the algo is related to well-known Procrustes rotation problem.

Comment: Is kabsch rotation is included in scipy?

Comment: I think there's a mistake - the paper and Wikipedia both talk about using det(V*U_t), not det(C). Or are the signs guaranteed to be the same? If so, is it shown anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this with an iterative optimum-search, and tested 2 versions.
I've taken the original arrays and centered them calling this arrays `cSRC` and `cTAR` .
Then I've done a loop with angles $\varphi$ between $0$ and $2 \pi$ , and for each angle I computed the error-criterion using the difference between the rotated $\small D=rot(\text{cSRC} ,\varphi)- \text{cTAR}$.

1. In version 1) I took as criterion the sum-of-squares of all entries in $\small D$ as $$err_1 = \small \sum_{k=1}^4 \small((D_{k,1})^2+(D_{k,2})^2)$$and the angle $\small \varphi$ at which the minimal error occured is equivalent the `kabsch2d`-procedure in @Karolis' answer.
2. In version 2) I took as criterion the sum of the absolute distances, that means, the sum  $$err_2=\small \sum_{k=1}^4 \small\sqrt{(D_{k,1})^2+(D_{k,2})^2}$$ and got a slightly different rotation angle $\small \varphi$ for the smallest error.

I don't know, which criterion fits your needs better.

Here are some results from the protocol.

> $$ \small \begin{array} {r|cc}
>  & \text{version } 1  &  \text{version } 2\\ \hline
>  \varphi &  -0.04895304&  -0.05093647 \\
>    \text{rotation} & 
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>    0.99880204&  -0.04893349\\
>    0.04893349&   0.99880204\\
>   \end{bmatrix} & 
> \begin{bmatrix} 
>   0.99870302 & -0.05091444\\
>   0.05091444 &  0.99870302\\
> \end{bmatrix} \\
>   \text{distances} &
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>  -6.80077266 & -0.86209739\\
>   2.79924551 & -9.33782500\\
>  -0.61309522 & 6.94156520\\
>   4.61462237 &  3.25835719\\
>  \end{bmatrix} 
>  &
> \begin{bmatrix}
>  -6.78017751&  -0.37062404 \\
>   3.35787307 & -9.36574874 \\
>  -1.16459115  & 6.95324527 \\
>   4.58689559 &  2.78312752 \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> \end{array}
> $$