# Complex valued design matrix

Tags: regression, estimation, complex-numbers

In statistics design matrix is fundamental concept.  It includes set of explanatory variables, for example in case of MRI data we use dc component, drift,physiological noise and so on. What will happen if the design matrix is complex valued? Does that turns out to be any meaningful notion in case of MR data? Here in this [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66088/analysis-with-complex-data-anything-different) design matrix is taken as complex valued for performing OLS for complex data.

Appreciate your answers