# How to represent a 2D start-point end-point data in a plot?

Tags: data-visualization

I have multiple particles located on a grid in the x-y plane. After running some simulation, I get the final positions of the particles in the X-Y plane. So say there are $N$ particles and I want to show their positions before and after the simulation. Is there a standard chart-type for this kind of data?

The only thing I can think of is to create two separate plots 'Before' and 'After' with point labels representing the individual particles. But the problem is that it is very likely that after the simulation, multiple particles may have the same final position.

Comment: My post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/66268/919 uses several methods to depict such data.  A *vector field* is a standard and natural way to depict such motions.

Comment: Thank you! The plot with filled red circles and empty blue circles with connecting arrows seems to be a good choice for my case.