# Why use complex-valued random variables?

Tags: random-variable, complex-numbers

**Edit**: This question has been posted on Math.exchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4101618/statistical-advantages-of-complex-valued-random-variables). To avoid duplication, please comment on the Math.exchange thread.

I am interested in random complex numbers and am trying to understand why to use complex random variables in statistics?

Complex numbers can equally be viewed as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but with a defined multiplication. This [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66088/analysis-with-complex-data-anything-different) addresses how to *do* linear regression with complex data.

I am aware complex-valued data arise in areas such as signal processing through complex numbers as a transform of real information. Alternatively, complex numbers can be constructed to represent a pair of real values and provide compact notation in other areas such as economics. A common discussed benefit is compactness of notation, but do we also have calculation or computational benefits by taking advantage of $\mathbb{C}$ and its multiplication?

To ask another way, once you have complex-valued data, are there specific *statistical* (e.g. distribution, modelling, estimation) benefits by continuing to treat it in the complex field, rather than using real bivariate statistical methods?

Comment: This question has been posted on Math.exchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4101618/statistical-advantages-of-complex-valued-random-variables). To avoid duplication, please comment on the Math.exchange thread.